# XSD regex pattern for comma separated values

Tags: regex, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have defined a XSD for a string parameter  which accepts 5 parameters that can have alphanumeric comma separated names(like a1,ABC1,jack2 or a1,b1,c,d1,e). But this creates the issue when i give a string like "a1,AB1" whereas a1,a2 works fine.  What is the wrong with the pattern value?

```
<xs:attribute name="paramList" >
   <xs:simpleType>  
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">    
   <xs:pattern value="([a-zA-Z0-9])*(,[a-z0-9])*(,([a-z0-9])*(,[a-z0-9])*(,[a-z0-9])*)"/>
  </xs:restriction> 
</xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this pattern for 1 to 5 comma-separated parameter names:

```
<xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(\s*,\s*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*){0,4}"/>
```

Notes:

- Parameter names typically *must* start with a letter, not a number.
- Space typically *may* exist before or after the commas.
- `{0,4}` occurrence specifier is better than expanded repeating.
- Parameter names sometimes allow `_`; add to `[a-zA-Z0-9]` (both places) if desired.

Comment: This was better even than my original one and exactly fits the definition i had for this.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> issue when i give a string like "a1,AB1" whereas a1,a2 works fine. What is the wrong with the pattern value?

In your pattern, you correctly consider lower and upper case letters for the first value:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9])*
```

However, you only allow lower case letters for the following values:

```
(,[a-z0-9])*
```

Hence, to solve your primary issue, add `A-Z` to the other brackets, as well:

```
(,[a-zA-Z0-9])*
```

---

Compared to your description, there is, however, another problem with your pattern. You say there are

> 5 parameters that can have alphanumberic comma seperated names

If I understand correctly, you thus want to allow a comma-separated list of (up to) five values.

However, you include the comma in the capturing group, and you mark the entire capturing group with an asterisk, meaning it may appear from zero to infinite times. Like this, the single pattern fragment

```
(,[a-z0-9])*
```

will match *any number* of comma-separated values, not just one. However, each of these values can consist of only *one* alphanumeric character. I imagine you want to write

```
(,[a-z0-9]*)
```

to enforce *one* comma and any number of alphanumeric characters instead.

Comment: Thanks..I modified as per this and it fixed adding a mix of letter with uppper/lower case. 
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">  
<xs:pattern value="([a-zA-Z0-9]*),([a-zA-Z0-9]*),([a-zA-Z0-9]*),([a-zA-Z0-9]*),([a-zA-Z0-9]*)"/>
</xs:restriction>
But how would i give an option to fill 1 or 2 or 5 in this ? Now it always expects that 5 comma seperated strings should be available?

Comment: @Rajesh: I'll abbreviate the patterns to show the principle, but you can use `?` to indicate optional (zero or one occurrence) parts: `a(,a(,a,a,a)?)?` Thus, you were on the right track with also nesting some value-spanning brackets, but the `*` did not do what you wanted.

Comment: With the ? i was able to create a pattern i wanted which can have 1 or 5 comma seperated strings .Thanks!
<xs:restriction base="xs:string"> 
<xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*(,[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*)?(,[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*)?(,[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*)?(,[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*)?"/>
</xs:restriction>

Comment: @Rajesh: But with that solution, you are again allowing 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 values, not 1 or 2 or 5, as indicated in your above comment. Is that what you are looking for? Still, if your problem has been solved, please mark one of the answers as accepted.